# Escaping single quote in XPath Binding WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xpath

I have a problem where I need to be able to use XPath in a XAML binding when the comparison I am making can have a single quote or apostrophe in it (As well as double quotes)

This is my XAML - I am trying to bind Text to be the *Value* attribute of the element with the *Name* attribute of "Field ' end":

```
<Canvas Width="9.5cm" Height="6.5cm" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Name="RootCanvas2">
  <Canvas.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="UserData" XPath="User" Source="MockUser.xml"></XmlDataProvider>
  </Canvas.Resources>
  <Viewbox StretchDirection="DownOnly" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Canvas.Top="1.0cm" Canvas.Left="0.0cm" Width="3.0cm" Height="0.8cm" >
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource UserData}, XPath=Fields/Field[@Name\=\'Field \&apos; end\']/@Value}" />
  </Viewbox>
</Canvas>
```

Below is an example of the XML that i am working with.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<User>
  <Fields>
   <Field Name="Last Name" Value="Smith" />
   <Field Name="First Name" Value="John" />
   <Field Name="Personnel ID" Value="000001" />
   <Field Name="Field &quot;quote&quot;" Value="000021" />
   <Field Name="Field ' end" Value="000056" />
 </Fields>
</User>
```

The issue is I can't escape the ' correctly in the XPath contained in the XAML.

I have tried using concat (doesn't seem to be available, or any other function), escaping with \' , just having ' etc. Nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

For some background, I don't have the ability to change the mechanism for the data. The user data will always be provided in XML as an XmlDataProvider.

I was able to something similar with double quote to:

```
<Viewbox StretchDirection="DownOnly" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Canvas.Top="0.0cm" Canvas.Left="0.0cm" Width="3.0cm" Height="0.8cm" >
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource UserData}, XPath=Fields/Field[@Name\=\'Field \&quot;quote\&quot;\']/@Value}" />
</Viewbox>
```

Is there a way to escape a single quote in this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use `XPath` searching some value containing quotes, you have to use element syntax for the Binding so that the `XPath` can be set as an attribute like this:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
       <Binding Source="{StaticResource UserData}" 
                XPath="Fields/Field[@Name=&quot;Field ' end&quot;]/@Value"/>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: I tried your answer and receive the following error message:

Error 1 Names and Values in a MarkupExtension cannot contain quotes. The MarkupExtension arguments ' Source={StaticResource UserData}, XPath=Fields/Field[@Name\="Field ' end"]/@Value}' are not valid. Line 9 Position 20. <removed>\visual studio 2013\Projects\WpfApplication1\WpfApplication1\MainWindow.xaml 9 20 WpfApplication1

Comment: @nwhite are you sure you tried exactly my code? The `Binding` should not be set ***inline***, it should be set as an independent element (see my code).

Comment: You are correct. works fine. Just now to do the age old problem - i'm am reading "Harry Potter". Excuse the stuff around, the first time i checked i was running my existing code.

Comment: I would like to upvote your answer but can't due to not enough rep.